# GLES-Render.cpp cocos2d-X causing compile time errors

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have copied the GLES-Render.h and GLES-Render.cpp files into my project and added them to the Android.ml file. Now the file is full of errors like

```
Symbol 'GL_FLOAT' could not be resolved
Symbol 'GL_FALSE' could not be resolved
```

When i click on any of these symbols eclipse opens up glew.h file or the some error open up on CCGLProgram.h. What am i doing wrong ? Is there OpenGL includes that i have to include ?

Kind Regards

Comment: what version of cocos2d-x?

Answer (score 0):

You cna check this GLES-Render.h/.cpp in this link. and also add GLES-Render in your android.mk file. [GLES-RENDER](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1Fbw3GLqN2rNm1BeU0tYkNuQmc&usp=drive_web)